# Zoom in/out options for text in eBook

Tags: readability, best-practice, zooming

I am currently working on a Zoom in/out option for an Ebook. Students are the users.  Also the maximum percentage of zoom is 300

Question in my mind is when the page is zoomed in which one of the below gives a best look and feel for a student or a best practise?

1. Page zoomed in - The text in the window is enlarged but page still fits to the window size
2. Page zoomed in - The text in the window is enlarged but the page needs to be scrolled right to read the rest of the line, and then scroll left to come to starting of the line and this goes on

Comment: On what device and/or platform is the Ebook going to be read?

Comment: Desktop and ipad. Not on mobile phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1 maintains the integrity of the content pane, and is similar to a large print version of a physical book. The text reflows.

Just as you have large print books for the sight impaired, kindle works the same way:

As a user, all I have to do is set my text size, and read on as normal, pressing the prev and next arrows. I don't have to pan and zoom to see the rest of the page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Option 2 makes more work for the reader. It penalizes those who cannot read at a standard size.

If you allow the page to go outside the container, you're forcing the user to both constantly scroll right, then down, then left.

Then repeat, again and again.

Option 2 seems more of a *pan and zoom* model. That seems more appropriate to a map, not a reading document. There's a lot more dexterity needed from the user, which will greatly interrupt reading flow.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I prefer the page that fits the window. This sounds user friendly with the fact that on 300 percent zoom the page looks crazy ;)

Comment: Oh, good, I thought I misunderstood option one.

Comment: From my experience that is the nice thing about reading an ebook format file that when you zoom you don't need to scroll, pdf works more like option 2 you need to scroll a lot and change pages is annoying, I guess that is necessary for magazines layouts were you can't take advantage of the ebook format.